# How to draw a section header in Android listview just like the Contacts app did ？

Tags: android, listview, header

I know how to display it in the screen, but when I use the Contacts app in my phone, I found its alphabet section header can be fixed in the top when I scroll the list.

How to make that happen?

Answer (score 1):

See the AmazingListView here, which is ListView with section headers.

It works similarly to the default Contacts application.

http://code.google.com/p/android-amazing-listview/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. That helped. I made it work for my project but I want to hide the header of the first row. I can change the colour by writing `view.findViewById(R.id.header).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)` in `bindSectionHeader` but can not hide the header with `view.findViewById(R.id.header).setVisibility(View.GONE);` Any help? :(

Comment: One interesting thing is that after executing the line `view.findViewById(R.id.header).setVisibility(View.GONE);`, the header is not occupying space but still visible. Still need some help. :|

Answer (score 0):

You need to implements

```
public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
return <return position where header start>
}
```

If you are using AlphaIndexer you can simply use

```
public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
return alphaIndexer.getSectionForPosition(position);
}
```

Hope that helps.